# What software can I use to automate diffing data in MySQL databases?

Tags: mysql, sql, liquibase

I know and love [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org) for schema migrations / schema diffing very much, but lately I have a weird use case to support - content management data migrations. Most of the non-enterprise ones tend to save a lot of structural data as SQL records and as such make it a PITA to keep such setups in sync.

So what I'm desparately looking for is a scriptable, configurable, multi-platform (Windows and Mac OS X at least) software that allows me to diff the data of two MySQL databases that share a common schema, that lets me configure which tables I'd like to diff (and maybe a few other things) and that outputs an SQL file with the differences so that I can stich that into my other liquibase migration files.

Yes, I know that there are such tools from RedGate, DBSolo, and what they are called (and I was astonished of the lack of Free Software tools in this area!), but they all seem to have at least two downsides: They can't be automated / scripted and / or aren't multi-platform.

**TL;DR:** Does anybody know a data diff lib / program for MySQL, ideally Java, that is scriptable via Ant or command line and that outputs SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try [SQL Workbench/J's](http://www.sql-workbench.net) [WbDataDiff](http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/compare-commands.html#command-data-diff) command.

It can be run in batch mode thus it's scriptable via commandline. You might even be able to run it from Ant as it is a Java application.

Answer (score 1):

Pt-table-sync which is part of the percona toolkit suite. It is written entirely in perl and has solid docs.

Comment: Thats a nice tool (and I only recently learned about the Percona Toolkit), however I need to be able to create SQL scripts from the diffs that can be reviewed by the developer before a checkin. It won't help me to just sync two db instances...

Comment: You can use the tool to create SQL scripts. Use the --print option instead of the --execute option. Read the docs for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you're looking for a diff tool, but perhaps you might also be interested in extracting and restoring data subsets.

- http://jailer.sourceforge.net/
- http://www.dbunit.org/howto.html

Comment: That Jailer thing looks really cool.